# How do you prevent a user from cancelling a page redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have a line of code:

```
location.href = 'payments/basic.php';
```

It works fine, but a user can simply press the Esc key to cancel the operation. I tried to use an event listener to prevent the Esc key from being pressed, but it only works while the user is on the initial page. As soon as they are being redirected, it stops working and they can quickly press the Esc key or the big X beside the address bar in their browser to cancel the redirect.

Is there a way I can completely prevent that?

Edit:
The reason I want to do this is that upon login, they are automatically sent to the index page. I have a flag in my DB which checks if a user has made payment. And then on the index page, I have a little script that queries the DB to check if the flag is true or false. If it's false, they are immediately notified that they are being redirected to make their payment. If at this point of redirection, they cancel, they will be able to remain on the Index page without payment.

Comment: Why would you want/need to prevent that? It's up to your user whether they want to navigate to your page or not. It's their browser, their device, their internet connection. Just because you wrote some code to automate that navigation does not remove their right to choose what their computer will do. What actual problem are you trying to solve in your application, which you think is caused by the user cancelling this navigation?

Comment: You cannot, that is a browser-level event, same as refresh, and you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: first of all, why are you trying to prevent that?
My guess is, there is something you don't want them to see... If that is the case, maybe work on fixing that instead of trying to prevent page cancellation

Comment: `If at this point of redirection, they cancel, they will be able to remain on the Index page without payment`...then make sure you have some code which, after they have delayed payment for sufficient time, ensures they can't do anything else useful on your site until they've paid. That should be sufficient motivation. You're trying to fix the wrong problem here. You could also do some server-side trickery to simply include the contents of basic.php inside index.php from the server side (instead of the regular content), so there's no opportunity _not_ to accept that content.

Comment: Leaving aside the why, I'd argue that the correct answer is "load faster!" If the user has time to press Esc, then your page isn't loading fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it the other way around?
Default to the payment page, if payment is already made, then redirect to index. lol.

Comment: Oh okay. So I can do that right at the point of login. That's pretty simple...

Comment: This makes sense, as long as it wouldn't be inefficient (e.g. if 99% of users have paid, then you're generating extra HTTP traffic which doesn't achieve anything). Note also that this would be far better done using a server-side Location header rather than Javascript, so that the payment page is never displayed (even for a moment) in the case where they've paid. Might be better to load index.php always, but change its contents to show the payment markup, in cases where there's been no payment. Same outcome, but less HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to prevent the Esc key from stopping navigation is to *not navigate away* from the original page at all. Instead of doing

```
location.href = 'payments/basic.php';
```

make an XHR or fetch request to `basic.php`, and populate the *current document* with the results, instead of loading an entirely new document - just like how a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) works.

(You will almost certainly want to make some changes to `basic.php`  - eg, have it return easily-parseable JSON containing the data to populate the page with instead of an HTML document)

Regarding the edit

> upon login, they are automatically sent to the index page

> If at this point of redirection, they cancel, they will be able to remain on the Index page without payment.

If you're trying to prevent access the the original page, then just *don't serve* the original page until you've checked the flag in the database. Don't serve the index page to begin with until you've validated the user's credentials. If they aren't authorized, redirect them *in PHP* (not in JS) to the payments page. No need to mess with the user's escape key.

Comment: That's pretty smart.

Comment: Arguably the user could also take steps to prevent the AJAX request from loading successfully too, although it's not quite as easy.